# Beginner in 3D | Imperfections appear when I use multiresolution subdivide

Tags: modeling

I'm make a monster 3D from a tutorial, I add details in sculpt mode and when I subdivide this imperfections appear. 
[image]
The solution or the cause is maybe simple but I don't know what to make...>.<

Comment: That looks like z fighting, which means you have faces ovelapping each other, try the "remove doubles" tool